# about node package 'squelize',what is 'dataValues' 's mean?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, koa2

My question is:

koa2 middleware `'/info' ctx.res.body ------>front-end get` Object doesn't have dataValues and other value .only have object like `{a:1,b:2}`

In middleware I get `ser` it have so many key-value like `{dataValue:{a:1,b:2},eviousDataValues:'xxx'}`

Why is the front-end Object not the same as 'ser' in ko2 middleware?

this is my code

```
let sequelize = new Sequelize('test', sqlOpt.name, sqlOpt.pwd, {
host: sqlOpt.host,
dialect: 'mysql',
port: sqlOpt.port,
pool: {
max: 5000,
min: 0,
idle: 10000
}})
let api = sequelize.define(
'api', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
  method: Sequelize.STRING,
  url: Sequelize.STRING,
  description: Sequelize.STRING,
  createTime: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  did: Sequelize.STRING,
  status: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  content_type: Sequelize.INTEGER
}, {
  freezeTableName: true,
  tableName: 'apilist',
  timestamps: false
})
module.exports = {
searchbyDid(params) {
  return api.findAll({
  where: {
    did: params.id
  }
})}}

router.get('/info', async ctx => {
  let ser = await ser_m.searchAll()
  for (let val of ser) {
    val.dataValues.item = await api_m.searchbyDid({
      id: val.id
    })
  }
  ctx.response.body = ser
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The response from Sequelize is always an Model Instance, Which is of the form.

```
{
  dataValues: [//All your data],
  previousDataValues: [//Old Values],
  ... //many more properties
}
```

If you don't need the instance, and just want the data. You can supply an additional flag in your query as `raw:true`. Docs are available [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#raw-queries)

So doing

```
Model.A.findAll({where:{/*Some Conditions*/},raw:true})
```

will return just the data as a plain JS object.

Comment: You could mark it as answered for anyone else who stumbles here

Comment: and I checked Sequelize instance.__proto__ , i find a function  , a name toJSON function,it return a Object, JSON.stringfy() is find this Object and then retrun this Object,don't return JSON.stringfy(mydata),so brother ,this is the key to my question,thank you